# will push notification still work after ownership transfer in iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am looking to transfer ownership of an app that uses push notifications from one account A to account B, when I transfer the bundle id is maintained but the seed id changes.

I use urban airship to deal with all the push notifications (works really well)

the bundle id is maintained when transferred (com.mydomain.myapp). The seed is (the 'XXYYZZ' before the bundle id changes from account to account.

This does not seem to be in the bundle id on urban airships account details - just the com.mydomain.myapp bit.

Push notifications still function fine.

My question (thanks for reading this far) is when I have to update the apns certificate in urban airship - this will have to be updated through the new account B's profile - which has a different seed id, will this break the connection between the apps current users devices and the new accounts push apns?

The bundle id without the prefix will be the same, does the seed id prefix have any bearing on the apns ssl certificate?

I hope this makes sense.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, for anyone else coming up against this as long as you dont change the bundle id you will be fine, push notifications are not affected by the seed id.

Comment: I just tested this as well. It seems that the old push certificates keep working when you transfer ownership. When you update the app, you generate new push certificates which seem to be able to send notifications both to the new version of the app and the ones already out in the wild even though they were created on different accounts.

Comment: What will happen to the certificates and prov. profiles? Will they be transferred too?