# About iOS app, Will the device token for push notification change after transfer account?

Tags: ios, push-notification, devicetoken

I am going to transfer my iOS app from an account to another one.

Regarding to above process, I have a question.

Will the device token for push notification change after transfer?

Comment: yes, in iOS 8 with new changes to Push Notification API it happens..

Comment: check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373721/will-push-notification-still-work-after-ownership-transfer-in-itunesconnect

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Referring to above link, I think the answer is no?

Comment: PNs are based on bundle id and pem files, as pem files are created with development keys and CSR indirectly. And these things not relates to account. So it no effects on PN.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After transfer, I think I must create a new client SSL certificate. It is not related to device token?