# Transferred iOS app - push not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

A previous developer stuffed a friend around and I am helping him make sense of where things are at and fix a few things. They transferred the App ID to his Apple Developer account but this process does not include the certificates as they are tied to the developer account.

As a result of the handover, all existing clients are no longer getting push notifications. I've created a new signing request, created the certificate and attached to the production push notifications. I downloaded the generated cert and attempted to use PushMeBaby to send to the app that I already had on my phone from before the handover. No message is being displayed, and there are no errors coming from PushMeBaby.

I would have assumed that existing apps would continue to work provided the requests are signed with the correct certificate, or do I need to redeploy the existing application?

I am using PushMeBaby to send to the production push notification server, not the sandbox.

Comment: I think you need to redeploy it. The exisiting apps are codesigned with old certs.

Comment: @FruitAddict that was my first thought, but the development/distribution certs are different to push so I'm really hoping we can get away without resigning & distributing.

Comment: I'd wait for more educated answer but according to my experience the push certificates are also generated for the app id, so when something changed with the app id it could've affected the push certs.

Comment: @FruitAddict thanks for your thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this section of Apple's documentation: [Transferring and Deleting Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html), specifically this part:

> After an app is transferred, its associated App ID is also transferred to the recipient’s Member Center account. If the transferor’s App ID was a wildcard App ID, it’s converted to an explicit App ID that exactly matches the app’s bundle ID. **Associated client SSL certificates for push notifications aren’t transferred. If the app uses Apple Push Notifications service (APNs), the recipient needs to create a client SSL certificate using Member Center to reenable it.**

Also, take a look at this question from someone who experienced the same issue a while back:
[will push notification still work after ownership transfer in iTunesConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373721/will-push-notification-still-work-after-ownership-transfer-in-itunesconnect)

I hope one of these will help. Good luck.