# I have to create new PushNotification certificate after transfer a app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I implement PushNotification in my application. I transfer my app on another iTunes Connect account. Now if i want to upload a new version of this app on transfered account then i need to make new push notification certificate ?

Comment: Don't need if bundle id not changed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373721/will-push-notification-still-work-after-ownership-transfer-in-itunesconnect

Comment: Then which certificate have to select on Xcode build setting at the time of uploading.

Comment: For the version on AppStore, you don't need to and cannot change the certificate. For new build one, you would better to create new one certificate. The xCode will help you to create new app id in your dev account, and you need to config the notification certificates manually.

Comment: If i create a new certificate on new account the PushNotifications will work ?

Comment: The old version on Appstore should work fine before you updating a new version.

Comment: And for new version i have to create new .Pem file ?

Comment: Yes, you do it for new version.

Comment: oK thanks for the help.