# iOS App transfer impact on Push notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, app-transfer

I am going to transfer one of my apps to another apple account. After reading some forums, what I have come to know is Push notifications will not work implicitly.

1. Some forums say it will work, until the APNS certificate is not revoked/expired, the push notifications will continue to work. But since "App ID" is transferred to another account and APNS is associated with App ID only. It should not work then?
2. If Push Notification will not work after the transfer, I am guessing I need the to create new APNS certificates and attach them to the "APP ID" in the new account and provide the same to the server team. In this case no new app submission would be required right?

Comment: Check out this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373721/will-push-notification-still-work-after-ownership-transfer-in-itunesconnect