# Submit App Update after App transfer to new account

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect, submit, push

As I've read in below stack-overflow post and many another post that push will work fine after App transfer.
like this post show:

[will push notification still work after ownership transfer in iTunesConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373721/will-push-notification-still-work-after-ownership-transfer-in-itunesconnect)

But my question is suppose, I need to create an app Update for Transferred App(which I got from another developer account by transfer process), 
do I need to create new push certificates before app update, need to create a new one before submitting an app Update?

Note: I've used FCM for push notification.
Please clear my doubts also it will be a great help, if you provide me some links about this information, which I don't know(App Update after App transfer to the new account).

Comment: Hey, One question regarding App Update, After app transfer
Here Firstly I need to delete the Version viz. 1.1 from first account
only then able to install 1.2(Version from new Account)
Any idea for Direct update without deleting the one from older account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you won't need to create a new APNS certificate for an app update.

The certificate is hosted on the server handling push notifications and that can be changed at any time. Keep a note of when the current certificate will expire and create a new one and replace it on the server before then.

If you don't know when the current APNS certificate expires, there's no hard in creating a new one now.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I appreciate that, but it is possible that same developer provisioning profile is used to upload An app update on new account?

Comment: Just use automatic provisioning and a profile will be created for you. It will be using the same app id so the same APNS configuration will be used

Comment: Hey, One question regarding App Update, After app transfer Here Firstly I need to delete the Version viz. 1.1 from first account only then able to install 1.2(Version from new Account) Any idea for Direct update without deleting the one from older account?

Comment: All builds have to be deleted from the first account before an app can be transferred, the transfer process will not allow you transfer without deleting them first. If you already have a release build on your phone from the app store that was downloaded from the first account, it will update properly when you download an update from the second developer account from the store.

Answer (score -1):

Its relatively simple, to transfer the ownership of an app to another developer without removing the app from the App Store. When an app is transferred it will keep its reviews and ratings and users will still have access to future updates.

Before an app can be transferred it has to meet the following criteria:

1. Both accounts can’t be in a pending or changing state, and the latest version of the agreements in the Agreements, Tax, and Banking section must be accepted.
2. No version of the app can use an iCloud entitlement.
3. No version of the app can use a Passbook entitlement.
   The App must have had at least one version that has been released to the App Store.
4. In-app purchase product IDs on the app can’t be the same as product IDs on any apps in the recipient’s account.
5. TestFlight beta testing should be turned off for all beta versions of the app.
6. Sandboxed Mac apps that share the Application Group Container Directory with other Mac apps cannot be transferred.

If all the criteria are met, you can follow the below steps :

Step 1: **Back up** :

It’s a good idea to keep a record of your appʼs metadata and pricing, note dates the app was available on the App Store, and save sales and download information.

Step 2: **Initiate the app transfer**

The team agent in your organization initiates the app transfer.

Step 3: **Accept the app transfer**

The team agent in the recipient organization accepts the app transfer.

**Step 2 elaborated :** 
1. In the App store page signed in with previous (Account you want to transfer from) account, click "My Apps" on the homepage. A list of all apps will display. Select the app you want to transfer and scroll to the 'Additional Information' section, click "Transfer App,' then click "Done."

2. Enter the Apple ID and Team ID for the recipient’s team agent, and click "Continue."
3. Read the terms, select “I have read and agree to the agreement presented above,” and click "Request Transfer."And click Done.

**Step 3 elaborated:**
1. Sign in to iTunes Connect as the Team Agent. A notice indicates that an app is ready to be transferred.

2. Click "Agreements, Tax and Banking."
3. Below "Transfer Agreements," click "Review" next to the app in the "Contracts In Process"  section.

4.Enter the new metadata.

5.Read the terms, select “I have read and agree to the agreement presented above,” and click "Accept."

You can see more info in this [blog](https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000012284-Transfer-your-app-to-another-iOS-Developer-Account)